# does encryption and disk wiping, using gutmann or dod, produce the same measure of entropy?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

does using aes 256 or some other crypto algorithm produce the same degree of randomness as that when using an erasing algorithm like gutmann or dod?

i mean is it possible to look at a "RAW" hdd and say whether its wiped or if it is encrypted?
is it possible to use the "disk wiping" argument as a plausible deniability method?i mean saying something like "the entire hdd is wiped with 35 passes of gutmann"

can any forensic examine the hdd expert say whether its encrypted or wiped?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm neither a forensic examiner nor attorney I can give my best guess analysis.

In the modern world, disk wiping is becoming more of a standard than a "hacker's best friend" due to risks of identity theft.  Simply wiping a drive, to me, would not be any more an admission of guilt than clearing a browser history.  It may play in the bag of tricks of semantics more than actual usability.

According to a `NIST 800-88' reports, there are different levels of disk wiping.  Software based disk wiping is considered "CLEAR"  level processes whereas Secure Erase is considered a "PURGE" level.  For Secure Erase, NIST considers one pass as being sufficient to render the disk useless for data recover.  The CLEAR level is still considered recoverable.

The best answer can be sought [here](https://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough/) by scrolling down to the comment made by Ryk Edelstein.

Answer (score 0):

A secure block cipher is also a strong pseudo-random number generator (see: [distinguishing attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguishing_attack)). As of right now, an AES-256 ciphertext is indistinguishable from random data.

However, that doesn't necessarily lead to deniable encryption. While the encrypted data itself appears to be random, certain aspects of disk encryption might prevent deniability.

For example, to boot of a HDD, unless you're using hardware encryption, at the very least the Master Boot Record has to remain unencrypted. Any other HDD can be fully encrypted, but whether a given program provides deniable encryption or not depends on its design. Refer to the **Whole disk** column in [Comparison of disk encryption software - Layering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software#Layering).

In addition, some programs provide plausible deniability by creating hidden volumes insides other volumes. Refer to the **Hidden containers** column in [Comparison of disk encryption software - Features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software#Features).

Comment: actually theres no bootloader involved coz i just want to use an external hdd to store data

Comment: In that case, as I said, it depends on the specific software you're using. AES-256 itself is able to provide deniable encryption, but any given program might not be.

Comment: so in case of the external hdd, the hdd has no kind of signature if truecrypt or diskcryptor is used.and since theres no signature, can i claim that i have erased the disk, not encrypted it?

Comment: Both programs provide this feature for non-system disks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks dennis, but am not looking for deniable encryption or something like the hidden os feature in truecrypt. i want to be able to deny that i am using encryption in the first place.

Comment: i want to be able to say "i dont even know what the word "encryption" means"

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: i mean cant i simply say that none of my disks are encrypted. i have wiped all with dan's nuke and boot of something like that

Comment: @john - you can claim whatever you like. The question is, who do you claim it to? And how will the claim benefit you? What will that let you get away with, or preserve? They'll never believe you don't know about encryption at all. Unless you manage to wipe everything else, they'll know you at least have Truecrypt, so you can't pretend total ignorance. The best you can do is have more plausibility in refusing to give up the keys (Honest, Judge, I wiped it - there is no key to give up!). And then they've got a big chunk of circumstantial evidence that you were up to whatever they say you were.

Comment: am claiming it to forensic experts

Comment: how r those guys gonna know that i've encrypted stuff.i'll simply say "the random data that u guys r looking at is the result of full disk wipe with gutmann 35 passes.i dont know anything abt encryption".encryption= gibberish; multiple pass disk wiping= gibberish.so y not use the "disk wiping" argument as a plausible deniability tool

Comment: The **Whole disk** feature achieves what you're talking about. Denying that you even know what encryption means is going to be hard. You're going to need some software to access the data on your encrypted drive, which you'd have to hide from potential investigators.